# MinimumDate and MaximumDate attributes of the date picker are not working in the Android 10 version real device

Tags: date, xamarin.forms, datepicker, format, max

I implemented date picker and time picker in xamarin forms project.

MinimumDate and MaximumDate attributes of the date picker are not working in the Android 10 version real device. same attributes are working in the emulator.

The same attributes are working in lower versions of real devices.

Format="D" attribute of time picker is using to show a date in the below format. Format attribute also not working in the android 9 & 10 versions of the real device and it's working fine in the android 9 & 10 versions of emulators.

Date format: "Wednesday, 21 July 2021" .

Are those attributes deprecated..?
In that case, they should not work in the even emulators also.

Comment: Unclear to me what happened. Please show the line of code that fails. "Not working" - what exactly happens - error? Some different output? Maybe a difference in language or culture settings on the real device vs emulator?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I test code `<DatePicker Format="D" MaximumDate="12/31/2021" MinimumDate="01/01/2021" />` at Android 10 device and Android emulator 8.1, it all returns `Thursday, July 22, 2021` have no problem.